# Associating Option Group with exisiting RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an existing MSSQL 12 Express RDS instance. I want to enable native restore and backup for this instance. Following the official documentation I created an Option Group. How can I associate this Option Group with my RDS instance using the web interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the list of RDS instances in the web console you select the instance, and then click Instance Actions -> Modify. In the modification page you can change the assigned Option Group among many other things.

Make sure you click "Apply Immediately" at the bottom of that page if you want the changes to take effect immediately, instead of waiting until the next maintenance window.

Comment: Will it be rebooted after applying changes?

Comment: According to this AWS doc no:


`4. Under Database Options, choose the Option Group that you created, and choose Apply Immediately and Continue. Review the information, and then choose Modify DB Instance. This Option Group modification has no downtime because instance reboot is not required.`


https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/